# Rakudo Star bundle 2022.02 build failed

Tags: build, raku

If this question should be in a more appropriate forum, please point me to it. Thanks.

I am trying to upgrade to star bundle 2022.02 and it failed. I feel it is too hairy for me to try to tweak the source code. What is the fix?

I downloaded the tar ball and unpacked it; then ran

```
./bin/rstar install
```

and the errors are:

```
[2022-03-12T23:18:15] [INFO]  Installing Raku in /home/lisprog/Perl6/rakudo-star-2022.02
[2022-03-12T23:18:15] [INFO]  Starting build on MoarVM
[2022-03-12T23:18:15] [NOTIC] Using /home/lisprog/Perl6/rakudo-star-2022.02/tmp/tmp.qVxYSNmS0X as working directory
[2022-03-12T23:18:15] [NOTIC] Build log available at /home/lisprog/Perl6/rakudo-star-2022.02/tmp/tmp.819bVtG6xv
[2022-03-12T23:20:30] [INFO]  Starting build on NQP
[2022-03-12T23:20:30] [NOTIC] Using /home/lisprog/Perl6/rakudo-star-2022.02/tmp/tmp.JQlrQlVRgO as working directory
cp: cannot stat '/home/lisprog/Perl6/rakudo-star-2022.02/src/nqp-2022.024/nqp-2022.024/.': No such file or directory
[2022-03-12T23:20:30] [ALERT] Build failed!
```

I also tried using git and curl, but same failure.

Comment: As it happens, I started trying to build star bundle 2022.02 yesterday, with the aim of updating the brew formula. The 2022.02 bundle seems to be broken in the following ways:

- There is a typo for the nqp version in `etc/fetch_core.txt` it should read `nqp_version=2022.02`;

- The `MIME-Base64` module is missing from `src/rakudo-star-modules`;

- `JSON-OptIn` and `Perl6-PathTools` are missing from both `etc/modules.txt` and `src/rakudo-star-modules`. On macOS a fix is required for setting a valid locale and there is a problem installing the `openssl` module that I am trying to resolve.

Comment: https://github.com/rakudo/star/pull/169

Comment: Thanks to @donaldh and his GitHub pulls... a new [Star release](https://rakudo.org/star) 2022.02.1 was published just now. Please give it a try... Thanks